# Understanding why $\int_0^{\infty} u^{\alpha - 1} e^{-u}du = \tau(\alpha)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Can someone be willing to show me the prove of why $\int_0^{\infty} u^{\alpha - 1} e^{-u}du = \tau(\alpha)$ is true. I'm confused as to why it is. I'm proving the Gamma Distribution pdf is equal to $1$, and I'm stuck here. I just want the comprehension and intuition behind it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: what is $\tau$? Maybe you mean $\Gamma$ instead of $\tau$? The LHS is the definition for $\Gamma(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ such that $\Re(\alpha)\ge0$. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you @Masacroso